# How to find the most common pairings of size n in a set of values out of all rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas

### MY DATA

Let's say I have the following dataframe where each row consists of a unqiue shopping cart:

```
pd.DataFrame({'0':['banana','apple','orange','milk'],'1':['apple','milk','bread','cheese'],'2':['bread','cheese','banana','eggs']})

        0     1       2
0   banana  apple   bread
1   apple   milk    cheese
2   orange  bread   banana
3   milk    cheese  eggs
```

### WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO

I am trying to create a list of the most common pairings of size n out of each of these shopping carts. For example, the most common pairings of size 2 would be `banana, bread` and `milk, cheese`

```
pairing      count
banana, bread  2
milk, cheese   2
apple, bread   1
...
orange, banana 1
```

*To clarify, order does not matter here, or in other words, whichever item shows up in the cart first is irrelevant. `banana, bread` is the same as `bread, banana`*

### WHAT I HAVE TRIED

I tried putting all unique values in a list and iterating through each row and bruteforcing the pairings with `itertools`, but this seems like a very hacky and unpythonic workaround, plus I didn't even get it to work propely.

Comment: `itertools` is actually the most pythonic and probably most efficient way to achieve this. You could do this in pure pandas but this would be less efficient ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to efficiently loop over the combinations of values per row (as [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)), then optionally convert back to Series:

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

out = pd.Series(Counter(frozenset(c) for r in df.to_numpy()
                        for c in combinations(r, 2)))
```

Output:

```
(banana, apple)     1
(banana, bread)     2
(apple, bread)      1
(apple, milk)       1
(apple, cheese)     1
(milk, cheese)      2
(bread, orange)     1
(banana, orange)    1
(milk, eggs)        1
(eggs, cheese)      1
dtype: int64
```